# Code will not send embed to discord webhook

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, discord, webhooks

```
    from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import threading
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook, DiscordEmbed
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

webhook = DiscordWebhook(url='WEBHOOK HERE')
PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=chrome_options)
TargetShipIt = '//*[@id="viewport"]/div[4]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/button'
uno = 1

def Target(ListingTitle, SKU, Price, URL, Abbrev):
    driver.get(URL)
    title = str('[**',ListingTitle,'**](','URL',')',sep='')
    SearchLink = str('https://www.target.com/s?searchTerm=',SKU,sep='')
    time.sleep(3)
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(ShipIt)
    except BaseException:
        if Abbrev == 2:
            embed = DiscordEmbed(title='title', color='FFFF00')
            embed.set_author(name='Onyx Monitors')
            embed.add_embed_field(name='Price', value=Price)
            embed.add_embed_field(name='SKU', value=SKU)
            embed.add_embed_field(name='Search Link', value='SearchLink')
            embed.add_embed_field(name='Status', value='Out of Stock')
            webhook.add_embed(embed)
            response = webhook.execute()
            print('OOS')
        Abbrev = 1
    else:
        if Abbrev == 1:
            embed = DiscordEmbed(title='title', color='FFFF00')
            embed.set_author(name='Onyx Monitors')
            embed.add_embed_field(name='Price', value=Price)
            embed.add_embed_field(name='SKU', value=SKU)
            embed.add_embed_field(name='Search Link', value='SearchLink')
            embed.add_embed_field(name='Status', value='In Stock')
            webhook.add_embed(embed)
            response = webhook.execute()
            print('IS')
        Abbrev = 2

XboxController = 1
while uno > 1:
    Target(ListingTitle='Xbox Controller', SKU='12345', Price='123', URL='https://www.target.com/p/powera-fusion-pro-wired-controller-for-xbox-one-black/-/A-79365603#lnk=sametab', Abbrev='XboxController')
```

Here is my complete code so far. I simply do not know what is happening, I assume a syntax error but python does not return any errors. I don't know what else to say here and it's making me say more so...
abcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabcabc